# Find ellipse nearest edge using current coordinates - Spritekit

Tags: swift, math, ellipse

This may be more of a maths question than one specific to Spritekit or Xcode but I wondered if anyone knew of a function that would give the desired results.

I have an ellipse created with the code below.

```
var shape = SKShapeNode(ellipseOfSize: CGSize(width: 400, height: 240))
```

I can use a touch event to find the position of the touch within the shape.

I would like to have a function that takes in those coordinates and returns the coordinates of the nearest edge, with the option of being able to reduce that by x amount (say 10%).

I can imagine drawing a line from the centre of the ellipse outwards but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach. Clearly, it would be possible using a formula.

Can anyone help with a function or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

*nearest edge*? Ellipses have no edges.
I suspect you mean nearest point on the ellipse.
Given: ellipse with semiaxes a and b, centered at (0, 0), and point P=(px, py)
Needed: coordinates of point on the ellipse circumference, closest to P
Lets denote A = a^2, B = b^2

Now with Lagrange multiplier method we can obtain

```
x = px / (k/A + 1)
y = py / (k/B + 1)
```

and substitute them in ellipse equation

```
x^2/A + y^2/B = 1
A * px^2 / (k + A)^2 + B * py^2 / (k + B)^2 = 1
A * px^2 * (k + B)^2 + B * py^2 * (k + A)^2 =(k + A)^2 * (k + B)^2
```

Solve last quadric equation for unknown k, find real roots (there are up to four roots), calculate x and y for every k, and choose the smallest distance to P point.